# Problem using string.IsnullorEmpty in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query in which i want to include those record which are not null or empty in database field but when i use string.isNullorEmpty it gives me error. How can i achieve this task my query is

```
from post in PostIdPostMeta1
join pstmt in postrepository.GetAllPostMetas() on post.int_PostId equals pstmt.int_PostId
where string.IsNullOrEmpty(pstmt.vcr_MetaValue) == false
select post
```

If i change **string.IsNullOrEmpty(pstmt.vcr_MetaValue) == false** to **pstmt.vcr_MetaValue != string.Empty** it give me **SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types** error

Comment: Boolean IsNullOrEmpty(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the error message seems reasonably clear - I suspect that if you want to be able to do this, you'll need to use an `nvarchar` field instead of `text` / `ntext`.

EDIT: It's not just the database field that needs to be the right type; it's also the type that LINQ to SQL thinks it is. You need to keep your DBML in sync with your actual database schema.

Comment: @Fraz: Are you absolutely *sure*? The error message strongly suggests it's not. Was it text / ntext at some earlier time? Perhaps you need to update the LINQ to SQL entities...

Comment: Yes my mistake i forgot to update the DBML after changing the data type in database

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried replacing

```
where string.IsNullOrEmpty(pstmt.vcr_MetaValue)
```

with

```
where pstmt.vcr_MetaValue != null && pstmt.vcr_MetaValue != string.Empty
```

?

Comment: it give me SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types error

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
from post in PostIdPostMeta1
join pstmt in postrepository.GetAllPostMetas() on post.int_PostId equals pstmt.int_PostId
where ((pstmt.vcr_MetaValue != "") && (pstmt.vcr_MetaValue != null))
select post
```

Answer (score 1):

If DB field is NTEXT, You can check if field is not like empty string. Here's an example;

```
from post in PostIdPostMeta1
join pstmt in postrepository.GetAllPostMetas() on post.int_PostId equals pstmt.int_PostId
where !SqlMethods.Like(pstmt.vcr_MetaValue, "")
select post
```

Comment: Like method does not check null fields, so I've removed null check from example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about which linq provider you are using, and from a quick google-ing it seems that IsNullOrEmpty is not universally supported. The answers that popped up while typing this look correct.